# PCA Why covariance matrix?

Tags: pca

At PCA why we find the Eigenvalues of the covariance matrix and not the eigenvalues of the matrix $A\times A^T$, where $A$ is the data matrix and $A^T$ its transpose? I saw a professor at YouTube who explained PCA but he said that the solution is the eigenvalues of $A\times A^T$.